# How to access to hidden directiory in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

How to access a hidden directory on Ubuntu. I have a have a directory named `.azerty`  I want to enter to this directory, like doing `cd dirname`.

Comment: Did you try doing `cd .azerty` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cd like you would normally.

```
cd .azerty
```

To list all folders including hidden you can use:

```
ls -a
```